# mpi_recv only recieving half of the data sent by mpi_send ? Utterly confused

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I am learning mpi with fortran. I have written a simple code which is as follows.

```
program arraypractice
use mpi
    integer pid, np, ierr, arraysize, i,msg, status(mpi_status_size)       
    integer dcount
    real*8  f(10), f1(10)

    call mpi_init(ierr)
    call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, np, ierr)
    call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, pid, ierr)

    if(pid==0) then
          do i = 1, 10
          f(i)=float(i)
          enddo
    endif

        msg = 1

    if(pid==0) then
         call mpi_send(f(1),6,mpi_real,1,msg,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    endif

    if(pid==1) then
        call mpi_recv(f1(1),6,mpi_real,0,msg,mpi_comm_world,status,ierr)

        call mpi_get_count(status,mpi_real,dcount,ierr)
        print *,dcount
        do i= 1, 6
          print *,f1(i)
        enddo
    endif

    call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end
```

I am compiling the code with "mpif90" command and then running it using "mpirun -n 2 a.out" command on my i5 dual core laptop with Arch Linux. My output looks like,

```
          6
   1.0000000000000000     
   2.0000000000000000     
   3.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000     
   0.0000000000000000
```

I am utterly confused about why the last 3 numbers are not being updated. Every time mpi_recv is recieving only half of the data that mpi_send is sending. I would expect the output to be

```
          6
   1.0000000000000000     
   2.0000000000000000     
   3.0000000000000000     
   4.0000000000000000     
   5.0000000000000000     
   6.0000000000000000
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is type mismatch between the type of the array elements and the datatype you provide to the MPI calls. `real*8` denotes 64-bit double-precision numbers, while `MPI_REAL` corresponds to the (usually) 32-bit single-precision type `real`. Therefore, MPI sends the first half of the data only.

Either get rid of `*8` in `real*8` to use single precision or replace `MPI_REAL` with `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION` or `MPI_REAL8`. The second MPI datatype (`MPI_REAL8`) is optional and might not be available in all MPI libraries.

Comment: Also note real*8 is not and has never been standard Fortran - I would strongly suggest you learn about the kind mechanism.

Answer (score -2):

You should also note that MPI is guaranteed to work only with Fortran 77 and C. It is not guaranteed to work with Fortran 90 (or later) or C++. MPI is not like a normal library it messes with the memory layout directly and can overwrite local variables unrelated to the MPI calls you have made. For instance I had a crash within MPI just because I had a local variable `integer i`. This variable played no role in my calls to MPI. When I chanced it to `integer, save :: i` (so not on the stack) everything worked!

Comment: This is incorrect. Please see http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf section 2.6.2 where it states 'When the term "Fortran" is used it means Fortran 90 or later'. C++ support has also been published but is now deprecated.

Comment: This is completely wrong. If the program changes behaviour due to stack layout, it is a clear sign of stack corruption. Check the correctness of all your subroutine and function arguments, especially their types and kinds. This is a common type of error and has nothing to do with MPI internals, only with the correctness of your code. Obviously, the `mpi` module must be for Fortran 90, because there were no modules in Fortran 77. And obviously, the `mpi_f08` module is for Fortran 2008, it is even named that way. MPI does support even Fortran 2008.